# Is the value of a probability density function for a given input a point, a range, or both?

Tags: distributions, terminology

This [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-68-95-99-7-rule-for-a-normal-distribution-b7b7cbf760c2) says

> A PDF is used to specify the probability of the random variable falling within a particular range of values, as opposed to taking on any one value.

Is it true?

this is the PDF of the standard normal distribution.

$$\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$$

plug in x=0 into the formula above, I can get the probability of taking on one value.

Does that post mean the PDF could be used both for point and  interval?

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4223/21054) by whuber goes into more detail of how to interpret the value of the PDF at a certain point.

Comment: Welcome to CV yaojp. I suspect notation may be playing a role in your perplexity: the $\varphi(x)$ function is the [*cumulative distribution function* of the standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) which is explicitly an integral from $-\infty$ to $x$ so its non-zero probabilities must come from intervals.

Comment: You can also interprete the density the following way: for a very small interval $[x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon]$ it holds: $P(X \in [x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]) \approx 2\epsilon f(x)$

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The citation is true. When you plug $x=0$ to the PDF function, you do NOT get the probability of taking this particular  value. The resulting number is *probability density* which is not a probability. The probability of taking exactly $x=0$ is zero (consider the infinite number of similarly-likely values in the tiny interval $x\in[0,10^{-100}]$).

To further convince yourself that this $\varphi(x)$ cannot be a probability, consider decreasing the standard deviation of your normal distribution from $\sigma = 1$ to $\sigma = \frac{1}{100}$. Now, $\varphi(0)=\frac{100}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ - much more than one. Not a probability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is $x\in[0..10^{-100}]$ for? Is it discrete? Would you please give a set notation, something like $\{0, ..., 10^{-99}, 10^{-100}\}$?

Comment: Sorry about the sloppy notation. Continous, not discrete - all numbers between 0 and $10^{-100}$. The point is that if $\varphi(x)$ was the probability of taking one particular value, the total probability for this tiny interval would be infinity.

Comment: +1 Welcome to CV, @Trisoloriansunscreen. I am amused by your name, assuming as I do, that it references Cixin Liu's trilogy?

Comment: @Alexis, correct :)

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating a bit on [Trisoloriansunscreen's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/430087/54186): it's very much true that you only got a probability *density* function. I'd like to draw an analogy for you. Imagine you have a 3D object, say some complex spaceship, and you know the mass density at every point.

For example, some parts of the spaceship might contain water, which has a mass density of $997 \frac{\text{g}}{\text{l}}$. Does this already tell you anything about the mass of the whole spaceship? No, it does not! Precisely because you only know this value at a specific point. You've got no information on how much water there actually is. It might be $1\ \text{ml}$ or $1\ \text{l}$.

Now suppose you know the amount of water, let's say $2\ \text{l}$. By simple multiplication $997 \frac{\text{g}}{\text{l}} \cdot 2\ \text{l}$, you get roughly $1994\ \text{g}$. I would like to make the point that you just did integration in disguise! Consider the following picture:

[image: 2D Cartesian coordinate system showing "Amount of water" (x-axis) vs "Mass Density" (y-axis) with a horizontal line at 997 g/l and a designated interval of 2l at the x-axis. The area of the "curve" (=horizontal line) is shadowed and amounts to the multiplication given before.]

The mass you calculated is just the greenly shaded rectangular area. This was only doable as a simple multiplication because the mass density was constant for the amount of water considered and thus yielded a rectangular area.

What if you had mixed forms of water, e.g. some gaseous, some liquid, some in varying temperatures and so on? It could look like this:

[image: Similar picture as before, but now mass density is not a constant function, but some arbitrary continuous function "going up and going down".]

Now for computing the mass you would need to integrate that mass density function over the amount of water. Do you see the **parallel to probability density functions** now? To get an actual probability (cf. mass) you need to integrate the probability density (cf. mass density) over some domain.

Comment: @Downvoter: Could you please include constructive feedback in a comment? :)